# Code keeps saving the document even though output is identical to original output?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, if-statement, for-loop

In my code below, for some reason it keeps writing the output data to file even though my output data is identical to the newly produced data...

I'm trying to make it so that it only saves when it's different, in order to recreate my problem run the script at least three times and it shouldn't be printing `again` more than once

#### Code example

```
import csv

def get_html_table(data):
    s = """<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Title</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <table id="gradient-style">
            <tbody>\n"""
    for row in data:
        s += '        <tr>'
        for counter, cell in enumerate(row):
            s += r'<td>{}</td>'.format(cell)
        s += '</tr>\n'
    s += """            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>"""
    return s


with open('testoutput.html', 'rb') as old_html:
    old_html = old_html.read()

identifyer = ""
with open('random.csv') as ifile, open('testoutput.html', 'wb') as ofile:
    data = []

    for counter, row in enumerate(csv.reader(ifile)):
        if counter != 0:
            datatoapp = [row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3]]
            data.append(datatoapp)

    html_data = get_html_table(data)
    old_html = old_html.strip()
    html_data = html_data.strip()

    if old_html != html_data.strip():
        if html_data:
            print "again"
            ofile.write(html_data)

print "done"
```

As you can see the above code turns the csv into a form of html, without some data included.

#### random.csv

```
data,data,data,data,data
data,data,data,data,data
data,data,data,data,data
data,data,data,data,data
data,data,data,data,data
```

Any ideas how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're opening the file and then comparing and because it's the same it saves nothing in the file.

Open the file after comparing for example your bottom section of code:

```
import csv

def get_html_table(data):
    s = """<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Title</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <table id="gradient-style">
            <tbody>\n"""
    for row in data:
        s += '        <tr>'
        for counter, cell in enumerate(row):
            s += r'<td>{}</td>'.format(cell)
        s += '</tr>\n'
    s += """            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>"""
    return s

with open('testoutput.html', 'rb') as old_html:
    old_html = old_html.read()

with open('random.csv') as ifile:
    data = []

    for counter, row in enumerate(csv.reader(ifile)):
        if counter != 0:
            datatoapp = [row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3]]
            data.append(datatoapp)    

    html_data = get_html_table(data)

if old_html != html_data:
    if html_data:
        with open('testoutput.html', "wb") as ofile:
            ofile.write(html_data)
```

Hope this helps :)
- Hyflex

Answer (score -1):

The following reads the entire file, whereas you probably intended to read a single line:

```
old_html = old_html.read()
```

P.S. I personally find this sort of reuse of variable names highly confusing.

Comment: I'm trying to compare the entire file, not just one line.